# Update Status in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

I've been trying to find a way to update the chart data within highcharts every 5 second. I'm collecting data from an MSSQL server using PHP and have been runnin gthis successfully.  I'm struggling with the calling of th latest data and passing it through to the chart.

Here is the php file planlivephp.php:

```
<?php
// CONNECT TO LOCAL SERVER
require_once('server.php');


// DATA TABLE 12a - PLAN DATA POINTS
$tsql12a = "SELECT * FROM AggCurrentPlanUtilStatus";
$stmt12a = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql12a);
$occ = array(0=>'#009900', 1=>'#FF0000'); // GREEN RED
$data12a = "";
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt12a, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)){
$data12a .= "{name: ";
$data12a .= "'$row[2]',";
$data12a .= " color: '";
$data12a .= $occ[$row[3]];
$data12a .= "', x: $row[6],";
$data12a .= " y: $row[7]";
$data12a .= "},";
}
$data12a = substr($data12a,0,strlen($data12a)-1);



// ECHO STATEMENTS TO CHECK DATA IF WORKING PROPERLY

// echo "$data12a"; 

// CLOSE THE CONNECTION TO THE SERVER
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt12a);
sqlsrv_close( $conn);                                               // closes the connection

?>
```

I've then added a getStatus function with a setTimeout of 5 seconds at the begining of the highcharts script to call the php file and load it to the div id.

```
$(function ) {

        getStatus();
    });

    function getStatus(){

    $('#chart1').load('planlivephp.php');
    setTimeout("getStatus()",5000);
    }
```

Here is the full code altogether with the javascript feeding the div id "#chart1" in the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mosaddek">
    <meta name="keyword" content="FlatLab, Dashboard, Bootstrap, Admin, Template, Theme, Responsive, Fluid, Retina">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">

    <title>INOVU Dashboard</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--external css-->
    <link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <!--right slidebar-->
      <link href="css/slidebars.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 tooltipss and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


  </head>

  <body>

  <section id="container" class="sidebar-closed">  <!-- LEAVE BLANK "" IF YOU WNAT THE MENU TO ALWAYS APPEAR ON OPENNING
      <!--header start-->
      <header class="header white-bg">
<!--<div class="sidebar-toggle-box">
              <div data-original-title="Toggle Navigation" data-placement="right" class="fa fa-bars tooltips"></div>
          </div>
          <!--logo start-->
          <!-- <a href="index.html" class="logo" style="margin-left: 20px">Ino<span>Vu</span></a> -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.html"><img src="../VUF/img/inovu_logo.png" alt="" style="height: 26px"></a>
          <!--logo end-->
          <div class="nav notify-row" id="top_menu">
            <!--  DASHBOARD ICON BUTTONS START -->
                <ul class="nav top-menu">
                    <!--home page-->
                        <li data-original-title="Home" data-placement="right" class="dropdown tooltips">
                            <a href="../index.html">
                                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <!--home page end-->
                    <!--map page-->
                        <li data-original-title="Location Map" data-placement="right" class="dropdown tooltips">
                            <a href="location.php">
                                <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <!--map page end-->
                    <!--floor plan page-->
                        <li data-original-title="Floor Plan" data-placement="right" class="dropdown tooltips">
                            <a href="plan.php">
                                <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <!--floor plan end-->
                    <!--dashboard page-->
                        <li data-original-title="Dashboard" data-placement="right" class="dropdown tooltips">
                            <a href="dashboard.php">
                                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <!--dashboard end-->
              </ul>
          <!--  DASHBOARD ICON BUTTONS END-->
          </div>
          <div class="top-nav ">
              <ul class="nav pull-right top-menu">
                  <!--<li>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control search" placeholder="Search">
                  </li>-->
                  <!-- user login dropdown start-->
                  <li class="dropdown">
                      <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                          <img alt="" src="img/avatar1_small.jpg">
                          <span class="username">Dave Dash</span>
                          <b class="caret"></b>
                      </a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu extended logout">
                          <div class="log-arrow-up"></div>
                          <li><a href="#"><i class=" fa fa-suitcase"></i>Profile</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Settings</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i> Notification</a></li>
                          <li><a href="../index.html"><i class="fa fa-key"></i> Log Out</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <!-- user login dropdown end -->
              </ul>
          </div>
      </header>
      <!--header end-->
      <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



      <!--main content start-->
      <section id="main-content">
          <section class="wrapper site-min-height">
              <!-- portlet page start-->
              <div class="row-fluid" id="draggable_portlets">
                  <div class="sortable">
                      <!-- BEGIN Portlet PORTLET-->
                          <div class="panel">
                              <header class="panel-heading">HSSMI Floor Plan
                                <span class="tools pull-right">
                                <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></a>
                                <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-remove"></a>
                                </span>
                                </header>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div id="chart1" style="width: 1000px; height: '100%';"></div>
                                    <div id="drag"></div>
                                    <div id="drop"></div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                      <!-- END Portlet PORTLET-->
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- page end-->
          </section>
      </section>
      <!--main content end-->
      <!--footer start-->
      <footer class="site-footer">
            <div class="text-center">
              &copy; 2015 INOVU &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <SCRIPT language="Javascript">
                document.write("Refreshed: " + document.lastModified +"");
                </SCRIPT>
              <a href="#" class="go-top">
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
      </footer>
      <!--footer end-->
  </section>

    <!-- js placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="js/draggable-portlet.js"></script>


  <!--right slidebar-->
  <script src="js/slidebars.min.js"></script>

    <!--common script for all pages-->
    <script src="js/common-scripts.js"></script>

      <script>
          jQuery(document).ready(function() {
              DraggablePortlet.init();
          });
      </script>

      <!-- HIGHCHART SCRIPT FILES -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Highcharts/css/HcHSSMImain.css"> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Highcharts/js/highcharts.js"></script> 
    <script src="/Highcharts/js/highcharts-more.js"></script>
    <script src="/Highcharts/js/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
    <script src="/Highcharts/js/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
    <script src="/Highcharts/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="/Highcharts/js/draggable-points.js"></script>
    <script src="/Highcharts/js/export-csvRob.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">  // PLAN INDICATING OCCUPIED OR UNOCCUPIED DESKS
    $(function ) {

        getStatus();
    });

    function getStatus(){

    $('#chart1').load('planlivephp.php');
    setTimeout("getStatus()",5000);
    }

    $('#chart1').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundImage: '/Highcharts/graphics/HSSMIPLAN.png',
            height: 600,
            animation: false
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        title: {
        text: null      //'HSSMI Occupancy Plan (Live)'
    },

        xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 1000,
        labels: {enabled:false},
        lineColor: 'transparent',
        minorTickLength: 0,
        tickLength: 0
    },

        yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 600,
        title: false,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        labels: {enabled:false},
        lineColor: 'transparent',
    },

    legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'ns-resize',
            point: {
                events: {
                    drag: function (e) {
                        $('#drag').html(
                            'Dragging <b>' + this.series.name + '</b>, <b>' + this.category + '</b> to <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(e.newY, 0) + '</b>');
                    },
                    drop: function () {
                        $('#drop').html(
                            'In <b>' + this.series.name + '</b>, <b>' + this.category + '</b> was set to <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0) + '</b>');
                    }
                }
            },
            //stickyTracking: false
        },

    },

    tooltip: {
            borderColor: 'rgb(43, 110, 151)',
            formatter: function () {
                return 'Sensor: <b>'+ this.point.name + '</b><br>X Value: <b>' +
                    this.point.x + '<br>Y Value: <b>' + this.point.y +'</b>';
            }
        },

    series: [{
        type: 'bubble',
        minSize: 25,
        maxSize: 25,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        draggableX: false,
        draggableY: false,
        data: [<?php echo $data12a?>]
        }]



    });

$('#getcsv').click(function () {
    var csv = "Series;Name;X;Y\n";
    $.each(Highcharts.charts[0].series, function(i,s){
        $.each(s.points, function(j,p){
            csv += s.name + ";" + p.name + ";" + p.x + ";" + p.y + "\n";
        });
    });
    alert(csv);
});

});

        </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions or corrections you could put forward.
Thanks
Rob

Comment: try invoking `getStatus()` in an anonymous function `setInterval(function(){ getStatus() },5000);`

Comment: What exactly doesn't work for you? Have you read [this tutorial](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data) ?